# How do I view "docker logs" in a specific time range?

Tags: docker, logging, timestamp, containers, filtering

I'm trying to extract logs from a Docker container for a specific time range. I know about the --since option but this is not suitable to me as I have a lot of logs that I do not want to view. Is there a more direct and simple approach?

I have tried docker logs --since